# Wordpress upload folder on separate server

Tags: uploads

I separate uploads folder from root to subdomain. It works on one server. If I move it to another server it doesn not work.

I think profblem with Upload Path. I used this settings ftp://user:password@server.com/, but it do nothing. WHat should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you export the sql file and edit to the correct path on the new server?  Then just import the modified sql file to the new installation on the new server?

Comment: I can see uploaded images in uploads.domain.com, but i can't upload new.

Comment: At first I move uploads folder to subdomain. Everything works. 
And then I decided to move it to another server. After that I have this problem…